# Different output on Function on assesment (Hackerrank) (FIXED)

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

So, for this assessment on Hackerrank i need to calculate the ratios on given input. So i coded but whenever iam running this on my own shell it gives me the right output ,but in the compiler from Hackerrank it rounds the results up to a full integer.

Down below my own code. The test input =

6
-4 3 -9 0 4 1

```
My Code = 

def plusMinus(arr):
    array = []
    positive_int = 0
    negative_int = 0
    zero_int = 0
    total_int = 0

#removing the first int from input & appending the rest of the input to the empty array
for i in arr[1:]: ***Error was in this line of code. Removed the parameter "[1:]" and it gave me the right output***
    array.append(i)
    total_int = len(array)

#calcuting with every integer in array if positive or negative and counting them
for i in array:
    if i >= 1:
        positive_int +=1
    elif i < 0:
        negative_int +=1
    elif i == 0:
        zero_int +=1

#calculate the ratio of the negatives and positives integers
pos_ratio = positive_int / total_int
negative_ratio = negative_int / total_int
zero_ratio = zero_int / total_int

#format to six decimal places
formatted_pos_ratio = "{:.6f}".format(pos_ratio)
formatted_negative_ratio = "{:.6f}".format(negative_ratio)
formatted_zero_ratio = "{:.6f}".format(zero_ratio)

#printing out the ratio's
print(str(formatted_pos_ratio))
print(str(formatted_negative_ratio))
print(str(formatted_zero_ratio))
```

---

Output in Hackerrank Compiler =

0.600000
0.200000
0.200000

and in my own compiler its:

0.500000
0.333333
0.166667

What am i doing wrong? (Bear in mind, i just started coding so my code is most probably not the best way to solve this.)

Comment: The result from Hackerrank is what your function produces if it is passed the array `[-4, 3, -9, 0, 4,1]`. From looking at the site, its not clear to me how Hackerrank passes the input to your function, but it seems they are only passing the actual array and not the first value (which is just the length).

Comment: I think there is an error in your logic if you look at then number positive integers as a ratio to total number of integers, in the example there are 3 (3, 4, 1) out of 6 = 0.5 and cannot = 0.6.  Hackerrank is expecting a different ratio.

Comment: @Tyberius Yes, that fixed it. I removed the first value, which in this case i already a given input for the ratio. After removing that it worked. Thanks